# Question about the major number of disk device files

Tags: rhel, devices

We have some older RHEL 5.8 systems running with the disk array (HP P2000) via the FC HBA (qla2xxx).
They all worked fine for many years, until recently when we suddenly noticed that there are a few lun disks from the same disk array with a different major number, 65!

So my questions are the two following points:

1. Does it mean that the one major number (of any devices) can at most own 256 same type devices?
2. If so, can one type of device have many different major numbers? How do they work together?

```
#
# cat /proc/scsi/scsi
Attached devices:
Host: scsi1 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
  Vendor: HP       Model: Ultrium 5-SCSI   Rev: Y5BW
  Type:   Sequential-Access                ANSI SCSI revision: 06
Host: scsi1 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 01
  Vendor: HP       Model: MSL G3 Series    Rev: 5.90
  Type:   Medium Changer                   ANSI SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi1 Channel: 00 Id: 01 Lun: 00
  Vendor: IBM      Model: ULTRIUM-TD5      Rev: D8D4
  Type:   Sequential-Access                ANSI SCSI revision: 06
Host: scsi1 Channel: 00 Id: 02 Lun: 00
  Vendor: IBM      Model: ULTRIUM-TD5      Rev: D8D4
  Type:   Sequential-Access                ANSI SCSI revision: 06
Host: scsi1 Channel: 00 Id: 03 Lun: 00
  Vendor: HP       Model: P2000 G3 FC      Rev: T251
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi1 Channel: 00 Id: 03 Lun: 01
  Vendor: HP       Model: P2000 G3 FC      Rev: T251
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi1 Channel: 00 Id: 03 Lun: 02
  Vendor: HP       Model: P2000 G3 FC      Rev: T251
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi1 Channel: 00 Id: 03 Lun: 03
  Vendor: HP       Model: P2000 G3 FC      Rev: T251
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi1 Channel: 00 Id: 03 Lun: 05
  Vendor: HP       Model: P2000 G3 FC      Rev: T251
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi1 Channel: 00 Id: 03 Lun: 06
  Vendor: HP       Model: P2000 G3 FC      Rev: T251
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi1 Channel: 00 Id: 03 Lun: 07
  Vendor: HP       Model: P2000 G3 FC      Rev: T251
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi1 Channel: 00 Id: 03 Lun: 08
  Vendor: HP       Model: P2000 G3 FC      Rev: T251
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi1 Channel: 00 Id: 03 Lun: 09
  Vendor: HP       Model: P2000 G3 FC      Rev: T251
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi1 Channel: 00 Id: 03 Lun: 10
  Vendor: HP       Model: P2000 G3 FC      Rev: T251
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi2 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
  Vendor: IBM      Model: ULTRIUM-TD5      Rev: D8D4
  Type:   Sequential-Access                ANSI SCSI revision: 06
Host: scsi2 Channel: 00 Id: 01 Lun: 00
  Vendor: IBM      Model: ULTRIUM-TD5      Rev: D8D4
  Type:   Sequential-Access                ANSI SCSI revision: 06
Host: scsi2 Channel: 00 Id: 01 Lun: 01
  Vendor: QUANTUM  Model: Scalar i500      Rev: 646G
  Type:   Medium Changer                   ANSI SCSI revision: 03
Host: scsi2 Channel: 00 Id: 02 Lun: 00
  Vendor: HP       Model: P2000 G3 FC      Rev: T251
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi2 Channel: 00 Id: 02 Lun: 01
  Vendor: HP       Model: P2000 G3 FC      Rev: T251
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi2 Channel: 00 Id: 02 Lun: 02
  Vendor: HP       Model: P2000 G3 FC      Rev: T251
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi2 Channel: 00 Id: 02 Lun: 03
  Vendor: HP       Model: P2000 G3 FC      Rev: T251
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi2 Channel: 00 Id: 02 Lun: 05
  Vendor: HP       Model: P2000 G3 FC      Rev: T251
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi2 Channel: 00 Id: 02 Lun: 06
  Vendor: HP       Model: P2000 G3 FC      Rev: T251
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi2 Channel: 00 Id: 02 Lun: 07
  Vendor: HP       Model: P2000 G3 FC      Rev: T251
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi2 Channel: 00 Id: 02 Lun: 08
  Vendor: HP       Model: P2000 G3 FC      Rev: T251
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi2 Channel: 00 Id: 02 Lun: 09
  Vendor: HP       Model: P2000 G3 FC      Rev: T251
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi2 Channel: 00 Id: 02 Lun: 10
  Vendor: HP       Model: P2000 G3 FC      Rev: T251
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI SCSI revision: 05
# 
# 
# 
# ls -l /dev/sd*
brw-r----- 1 root disk  8,   0 Jun 22  2021 /dev/sda
brw-r----- 1 root disk  8,  16 Jun 22  2021 /dev/sdb
brw-r----- 1 root disk  8,  32 Jun 22  2021 /dev/sdc
brw-r----- 1 root disk  8,  48 Jun 22  2021 /dev/sdd
brw-r----- 1 root disk  8,  64 Jun 22  2021 /dev/sde
brw-r----- 1 root disk  8,  80 Jun 22  2021 /dev/sdf
brw-r----- 1 root disk  8,  96 Jun 22  2021 /dev/sdg
brw-r----- 1 root disk  8, 112 Jun 22  2021 /dev/sdh
brw-r----- 1 root disk  8, 128 Jun 22  2021 /dev/sdi
brw-r----- 1 root disk  8, 144 Jun 22  2021 /dev/sdj
brw-r----- 1 root disk  8, 160 Jun 22  2021 /dev/sdk
brw-r----- 1 root disk  8, 176 Jun 22  2021 /dev/sdl
brw-r----- 1 root disk  8, 192 Jun 22  2021 /dev/sdm
brw-r----- 1 root disk  8, 208 Jun 22  2021 /dev/sdn
brw-r----- 1 root disk  8, 224 Jun 22  2021 /dev/sdo
brw-r----- 1 root disk  8, 240 Jun 22  2021 /dev/sdp
brw-r----- 1 root disk 65,   0 Jun 22  2021 /dev/sdq
brw-r----- 1 root disk 65,  16 Jun 22  2021 /dev/sdr
brw-r----- 1 root disk 65,  32 Jun 22  2021 /dev/sds
brw-r----- 1 root disk 65,  48 Jun 22  2021 /dev/sdt
# 
#
```